# Jquery change class on click

Tags: jquery, class, show-hide

I have put together a page which has a sidebar, when you click then menu in the sidebar it shows/hides divs.

http://www.prostatecymru.com/prostate/

The menu in the side is using this piece of code:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <ul id="menu-profile" class="menu">
        <li><a class="button" id="showdiv1">Show Div 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" id="showdiv2">Show Div 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" id="showdiv2">Show Div 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the main content is using this code:

```
<div id="div1">
    Content Div 1
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none;">
    Content Div 2
</div>
<div id="div3" style="display: none;">
    Content Div 3
</div>
```

And the jQuery being used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#showdiv1').click(function() {
            $('div[id^=div]').hide();
            $('#div1').show();
        });
        $('#showdiv2').click(function() {
            $('div[id^=div]').hide();
            $('#div2').show();
        });
        $('#showdiv3').click(function() {
            $('div[id^=div]').hide();
            $('#div3').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

It does exactly as I want it to but one thing. I just want the `a` in the menu to be highlighted when the user has selected the section to show. My thought is to use `.selected` instead of `.button` on the selected item. I can set `.selected` for the first item which looks cool but I want when you change the the link for the `.selected` to move to the actually selected item. How can I do this. I have read a few guides but it isn't exactly what I want or it doesn't work.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks

Comment: You should first refactoring your code

Comment: Your HTML uses the same id twice ... maybe copy/paste issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same method that you are using to show/hide the divs:

```
$('#showdiv1').click(function() {
    $('div[id^=div]').hide();
    $('#div1').show();

    $('a[id^=showdiv]').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Awesome - did exactly what I wanted - thank you so much man. Love it.

Comment: The resulting code is around 20 lines and will only ever handle the 3 divs in the demo, if you want to add more divs you add more code which could grow exponentially. Using code from roasted's answer or my own will see a much more modular, concise codebase.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is there, with little refactoring:

http://jsfiddle.net/s7E3z/

```
$('.menu a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showdiv(this);
    $('.menu a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('.menu a:eq(0)').click();

function showdiv(sender) {
    var idTarget = sender.id.replace('show','');
     $('.container div').removeClass('selected');
    $('#'+idTarget ).addClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try, as roasted suggested, refactoring your code and then adding new functionality. Here is a quick snippet (with the html slightly altered):

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var idNumber = $(this).attr("id").replace("show", "");
    $(".display").hide();
    $("#div" + idNumber).show();
    $(".button").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

and a working fiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uRpM3/2/)